# SharePoint 2013 - adding email addresses to a group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

Within Site Settings of SharePoint 2013, is there a way I can import multiple email addresses at one time into a specific Group, rather than one at a time?

If so what is the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group membership box is a multiline text box. So you can create email addresses in format

```
user1@domain.com; user2@domain.com
```

Etc. and then copy and paste it into the box. Then press Share button.

Comment: awesome.  the only part that takes time is simply converting a list in excel, to multiple email address values that are separated by semicolon.  thanks!

Comment: If its in excel you can even create it easily. http://superuser.com/questions/240858/convert-a-column-into-a-comma-separated-list